# Getting undefined in a function used in module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I'm trying to make a function which upon using gives a expected result like this

```
{
  id: 'ID_OF_THE_USER',
  username: 'USERNAME_OF_THE_USER',
  avatar: 'AVATAR_ID_OF_THE_USER',
  discriminator: 'THE_TAG',
  public_flags: SOME_NUMBER,
  banner: null,
  banner_color: 'A_HEXCODE',
  accent_color: SOME_NUMBER
}
```

However, I get the correct result when I use the function in my **main.js** file, but when I have the function in another file (for example: **function.js**) and use **module.exports** in that external file and use that function in the **main.js** file, I get **undefined**.

The Function which I am talking abt:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('MyBotToken');

client.api.users('SomeUserID').get().then((result) => { return result; });
```

My current **function.js** file:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports =
{
   user: function(UserID)
    {
       const client = new Discord.Client();

       client.login('MyBotToken');

       client.api.users(UserID).get().then((result) => { return result; });
    }
}
```

My current **main.js** file:

```
const details = require('./function');

const userInfo = details.user('SomeUserID');

console.log(userInfo);
```

Now when I run my **main.js** file, I get **undefined**.
Any help will be appreciated !

My Node version: 14.16
My Discord.js version: 12.5.3

Comment: Your exported function has no `return` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues. The first is that your function `user()` does not have a return statement and thus does not return any value at all. The `return result` does not apply to the scope of `user()`, but only to the anonymous function passed to `.then()`. Then whole expression `.then((result) => { return result; })` doesn't have any effect at all in your example since any returned value from a function passed to `.then()` of a promise would itself automatically be wrapped in a promise.

The second issue is that your code in `main.js` does not expect a promise. To "get" the value from the promise returned from the Discord API, you have to either use `await` in a context where that is possible (inside an `async` function or at the top level of a ES module) or using `.then()` do assign a function to handle the result when the promise resolves. You cannot get the value back to a "non-asynchronous" scope.

What you could to mitigate these issues, is to rewrite `function.js` to

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  user: function(UserID) {
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    client.login('MyBotToken');
    return client.api.users(UserID).get();
  }
}
```

and `main.js` to

```
const details = require('./function');
details
  .user('SomeUserID')
  .then((userInfo) => { console.log(userInfo); });
```

If you instead were call your `user()` function inside an `async` function, you could simply do

```
const details = require('./function');
const userInfo = await details.user('SomeUserID');
console.log(userInfo);
```

Comment: hey @Mikael
I used this on my main.js
```
const details = require('./function');
const userInfo = await details.user('SomeUserID');
console.log(userInfo);
```
but i got an error stating SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function, pls help :)

Comment: hey @Mikael ! actually, nvm i found the answer for my problem
> You cannot get the value back to a "non-asynchronous" scope.